# Apache radius auth works with firefox not with chrome

Tags: apache-2.2, radius

I am using mod_auth_radius with apache2.2

Here is the relevant config in the site section:

```
<IfModule radius_auth_module>
  AddRadiusAuth localhost:1812 test 5:3
  AddRadiusCookieValid 5
</IfModule>

        <Location />
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "RADIUS"
                AuthBasicProvider radius
                AuthRadiusCookieValid 5
                AuthRadiusActive On
                require valid-user
        </Location>
```

The authentication itself is working but with Chrome it keeps asking for username and pass on every page (eg I click on a menu it asks for auth again...). With Firefox 1 auth at the beginning is enough. Did anyone run into this issue?